# Laravel, where, orwhere in main table an pivot table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I have two tables with belongsToMany relation: **message_topics** and **users**

The pivot table is **message_topics_users** and contains 2 columns: message_id and user_id.

In table **message_topics**, I have a field called *sender_id*

I'm trying to write the correct eloquent syntax to get all the records:

where message_topics.sender_id = $user_id
  OR Message_topics_users.receiver_id = $user_id

I tried many things, like for instance:

```
$topics = MessageTopic::where('sender_id', $user_id)
    ->wherePivot('receiver_id', $user_id)->orderBy('sent_at','desc')->get();
```

Any idea?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming the belongsToMany relationship for `users` in the `MessageTopic` is just called `users`?

Comment: Can you please give feedback on the answers?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method (or in this case the `orWhereHas` method):

```
$topics = MessageTopic::where('sender_id', $user_id)
    ->orWhereHas('users', function ($query) use ($user_id) {
        $query->where('id', $user_id);
    })
    ->orderBy('sent_at', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have two relationships from the topics? Since it's too arbitrary to use both columns and the same relationship... Like this

```
//On your MessageTopic model
public function sender(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'message_topics_users', 'message_id', 'sender_id');
}

public function receiver(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'message_topics_users', 'message_id', 'receiver_id'));
}
```

Then you can use whereHas and orWhereHas like this:

```
//Again assuming you have your User model loaded as $user
$topics = App\Topic::whereHas('sender', function($q) use($user){
    $q->where('sender_id', '=', $user->id);
})
->orWhereHas('receiver', function($q) use($user){
   $q->where('receiver_id', '=', $user->id
})
->orderByDesc('sent_at')
->get();
```

whereHas and orWhereHas both query the model (MessageTopic in this case) checking for the existence of the specified relationship (`App\Topic::whereHas('sender')...`). They also allow you to pass the constraint that you're looking for (`function($q) use($user){ $q->... }`)

So it is basically saying "Give me ONLY the MessageTopics that have a Sender or Receiver with the id `$user->id`"